# JSF, Primefaces, <p:fileupload> parou de funcionar após atualização do chrome

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, google-chrome

O **fileupload** funcionava perfeitamente até 3 atualizações do Chrome atrás, no Firefox nunca funcionou, procurei em toda a internet alguma solução ou erro parecido e não tive sucesso.

A página em questão deveria anexar o arquivo para então enviar, acontece que quando clicado no botão a janela para escolha do arquivo não abre.

**Código do upload:**

```html
<div class="botoesAnexo">
  <div class="botoesAnexoLeft">
   <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{cadastroDocumentoController.handleFileUpload}"
    label="Procurar..." mode="advanced"
    skinSimple="false" update="anexoDocumento"
    dragDropSupport="true"
    auto="true"
    multiple="true"
    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf|doc|zip|tar|rar|xls|ppt|docx|tif|jpe?g)$/"
    />
 </div>
</div>
```

**Código cadastroDocumentoController:**

```js
package br.com.sysmar.sysportal.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;

import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultStreamedContent;
import org.primefaces.model.StreamedContent;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import br.com.sysmar.sysportal.help.ArquivoAnexoHelp;
import br.com.sysmar.sysportalmodel.interfaceFacade.IConfiguracaoFacade;
import br.com.sysmar.sysportalmodel.interfaceFacade.IDocumentoFacade;
import br.com.sysmar.sysportalmodel.interfaceModel.IArquivoAnexo;
import br.com.sysmar.sysportalmodel.interfaceModel.ICategoria;
import br.com.sysmar.sysportalmodel.interfaceModel.IDocumento;
import br.com.sysmar.sysportalmodel.interfaceModel.IEntidade;
import br.com.sysmar.sysportalmodel.interfaceModel.IFiltro;
import br.com.sysmar.sysportalmodel.interfaceModel.IOpcaoFiltro;
import sysmarutils.DateUtils;
import sysmarutils.exceptions.WarningException;

@ManagedBean(name = "cadastroDocumentoController")
@Controller
@Scope("view")
public class CadastroDocumentoController {
 
 @Autowired
 private IDocumentoFacade documentoFacade;
 
 @Autowired
 private IConfiguracaoFacade configuracaoFacade;
 
 private Long categoriaId;
 
 private Long documentoId;
 
 private ICategoria categoria;
 
 private IArquivoAnexo anexo;
 
 private ArquivoAnexoHelp anexoHelp;
 
 private IEntidade entidade;
 
 private String tamanhoArquivo;
 
 private IDocumento documento;
 
 private Date dataDocumento;
 
 private StreamedContent file;
 
 private ArrayList<ArquivoAnexoHelp> listaAnexo = new ArrayList<ArquivoAnexoHelp>();
 
 private ArrayList<IFiltro> filtroList = new ArrayList<IFiltro>();
 
 private IOpcaoFiltro[] opcaoFiltroSelecionadaList = new IOpcaoFiltro[10];
 
 public boolean init;
 
 public boolean apresentaInformativo;
 
 FacesContext context;
 
 @Transactional
 public void inicializar() throws Exception {
  if(init == false) {
   entidade = configuracaoFacade.carregarEntidade();

   if(categoriaId != null) 
    initCategoria();
   else if(documentoId != null)
    initDocumento();
   else
    documento = documentoFacade.novoDocumento();
   
   init = true;
  }
 }

 private void initDocumento() {
  documento = documentoFacade.recuperarDocumento(documentoId);
  categoria = documento.getCategoria();
  listaAnexo = new ArrayList<ArquivoAnexoHelp>();
  preencherDatas();
  preencherFiltroList(documento.getCategoria());
  documento.getOpcaoFiltroList();

  carregarOpcaoFiltroSelecionadas(documento);
  
  ICategoria categoriaSelecionada = documento.getCategoria();
  
  if(documento.getArquivoAnexoList() != null)
   recuperarAnexos(categoriaSelecionada);
  
  if(!documento.getInformativo().isEmpty()) 
   apresentaInformativo = true;
 }
 
 private void carregarOpcaoFiltroSelecionadas(IDocumento documento) {
  int i = 0;
  Iterator<IOpcaoFiltro> opcaoFiltroList = documento.getOpcaoFiltroList();
  while (opcaoFiltroList.hasNext()) {
   opcaoFiltroSelecionadaList[i] = opcaoFiltroList.next();
   i++;
  }
 }

 private void preencherFiltroList(ICategoria categoria) {
  Iterator<IFiltro> categoriaIterator = categoria.getFiltroList();
  while (categoriaIterator.hasNext()) {
   IFiltro filtro = categoriaIterator.next();
   filtro.getOpcaoFiltroList();
   filtroList.add(filtro);
  }
 }

 private void initCategoria() {
  categoria = documentoFacade.recuperarCategoria(categoriaId);
  listaAnexo = new ArrayList<ArquivoAnexoHelp>();
  preencherFiltroList(categoria);
  
  documento = documentoFacade.novoDocumento();
  documento.setCategoria(categoria);
  documento.setAtivo(true);
  
  preencherDatas();
 }

 @Transactional
 public String gravar() throws WarningException {
  try {
   if(apresentaInformativo && documento.getInformativo().isEmpty()) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("cadastro:messages", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Informativo do documento não informado", null));
    return "erro";
    
   } else if(!apresentaInformativo) {
    documento.setInformativo("");
   }
   
   documento.setDataDocumento(DateUtils.getCalendar(getDataDocumento()));
   autualizarOpcaoFiltro();
   documentoFacade.gravarDocumento(documento);
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("cadastro:messages", new FacesMessage("Cadastro Realizado com sucesso"));
   
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("listCategorias.xhtml?mensagemSucesso=true");
   
   init = false;
   
   categoriaId = null;
   documentoId = null;
   
   listaAnexo = new ArrayList<ArquivoAnexoHelp>();
   
   return "sucesso";
   
  } catch (Exception e) {
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("cadastro:messages", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, e.getMessage().toString(), null));
   return "erro";  
  }
  
 }

 private void autualizarOpcaoFiltro() {
  Iterator<IFiltro> filtroList = categoria.getFiltroList();
  
  while (filtroList.hasNext()) {
   IFiltro filtro = filtroList.next();
   IOpcaoFiltro opcaoSelecionada = getOpcaoSelecionada(filtro);
   excluirOpcaoFiltro(filtro);
   if (opcaoSelecionada != null)
    documento.incluirOpcaoFiltro(opcaoSelecionada);
  }
 }

 private void excluirOpcaoFiltro(IFiltro filtro) {
  Iterator<IOpcaoFiltro> opcaoFiltroList = documento.getOpcaoFiltroList();
  while(opcaoFiltroList.hasNext()) {
   IOpcaoFiltro opcaoFiltro = opcaoFiltroList.next();
   if (opcaoFiltro.getFiltro().equals(filtro)) {
    documento.excluirOpcaoFiltro(opcaoFiltro);
    return;
   }
  }
 }
 
 public Integer getIndex(IFiltro filtro) {
  if (filtro == null) return 10;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < opcaoFiltroSelecionadaList.length; i++) {
   if(opcaoFiltroSelecionadaList[i] != null && filtro.equals(opcaoFiltroSelecionadaList[i].getFiltro()))
    return i;
  }
  
  return getProximoIndexVazio();
 }

 private Integer getProximoIndexVazio() {
  for (int i = 0; i < opcaoFiltroSelecionadaList.length; i++) {
   if (opcaoFiltroSelecionadaList[i] == null)
    return i;
  }
  
  return null;
 }
 
 private IOpcaoFiltro getOpcaoSelecionada(IFiltro filtro) {
  for (IOpcaoFiltro opcaoFiltro : opcaoFiltroSelecionadaList) {
   if (opcaoFiltro != null && opcaoFiltro.getFiltro().equals(filtro))
    return opcaoFiltro;
  }

  return null;
 }

 @Transactional
 public String removerDocumento() throws WarningException {
  try {
   if(documento != null) {
    
    IDocumento documentoSelecionado;
    documentoSelecionado = documentoFacade.recuperarDocumento(documento.getId());
    
    documentoFacade.excluirDocumento(documentoSelecionado);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("cadastro:messages", new FacesMessage("Remoção Realizada com sucesso"));
    
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("listCategorias.xhtml?mensagemRemocaoSucesso=true");
    return "sucesso";
   }
   
  } catch (Exception e) {
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("cadastro:messages", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, e.getMessage().toString(), null));
   return "erro";  
  }
  
  return null;
  
 }
 
 private void recuperarAnexos(ICategoria categoriaSelecionada) {
  Iterator<IArquivoAnexo> anexosDocumento = documento.getArquivoAnexoList();
  while (anexosDocumento.hasNext()) {
   IArquivoAnexo anexo = anexosDocumento.next();
   ArquivoAnexoHelp anexoHelp = new ArquivoAnexoHelp();
   
   anexoHelp.setId(anexo.getId());
   anexoHelp.setNomeArquivo(anexo.getNomeArquivo());
   anexoHelp.setDataAnexo(anexo.getDataAnexo());
   
   Long tamanho = anexo.getTamanho();
   String tamanhoCalculado = calculaTamanhoArquivo(tamanho);
   anexoHelp.setTamanho(tamanhoCalculado);
   
   String caminho = anexo.getNomeArquivoDiretorio(categoriaSelecionada.getDiretorioAnexos(entidade));
   anexoHelp.setCaminhoAnexo(caminho);
   
   File arquivo = new File(anexoHelp.getCaminhoAnexo());
   
   if(arquivo.exists()) {
    anexoHelp.setArquivoNovo(false);
    anexoHelp.setArquivoExistente(true);
    
    String extencao = FilenameUtils.getExtension(anexo.getNomeArquivo());
    anexoHelp.setExtensaoArquivo(extencao.toLowerCase());

   } else {
    anexoHelp.setArquivoNovo(true);
    anexoHelp.setArquivoExistente(false);     
   }
   
   listaAnexo.add(anexoHelp);      
  }
 }
 
 public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {
  UploadedFile file = event.getFile();
  
  ArquivoAnexoHelp anexoHelp = new ArquivoAnexoHelp();
  InputStream stream = event.getFile().getInputstream();
  
  anexo = documentoFacade.novoArquivoAnexo();
  anexo.setNomeArquivo(file.getFileName());
  anexoHelp.setNomeArquivo(file.getFileName());
  
  anexo.setDataAnexo(Calendar.getInstance());
  anexoHelp.setDataAnexo(Calendar.getInstance());
  
  anexo.setInputStreamFile(stream);
  anexo.setTamanho(file.getSize());
  
  String tamanho = calculaTamanhoArquivo(file.getSize()); 
  setTamanhoArquivo(tamanhoArquivo);
  anexoHelp.setTamanho(tamanho);
  
  String caminho = documento.getCategoria().getDiretorioAnexos(entidade);
  anexoHelp.setCaminhoAnexo(caminho);
  anexoHelp.setArquivoNovo(true);
  
  documento.incluirAnexo(anexo);
  
  listaAnexo.add(anexoHelp);
  
  
    }
 
 private String calculaTamanhoArquivo(long tamanho) {
  long tamanho_kilobytes = tamanho / 1024 ;
  
  long tamanho_mb = tamanho_kilobytes / 1024;
  
  if(tamanho_mb > 0) {
   tamanhoArquivo = tamanho_mb + " MB ";
  } else {
   tamanhoArquivo = tamanho_kilobytes + " KB ";
  }
  return tamanhoArquivo;
 }
 
 public void prepararArquivo(ArquivoAnexoHelp anexoHelp) {
  if(anexoHelp != null) {
   this.anexoHelp = anexoHelp;
  }
 }
 
 public StreamedContent getFile() {
  try {
   ArquivoAnexoHelp arquivoAnexo = anexoHelp;
   String caminho = arquivoAnexo.getCaminhoAnexo();
   
   InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(caminho);
   file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/pdf", arquivoAnexo.getNomeArquivo());
  } catch (Exception e) {
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("cadastro:messages", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Arquivo não encontrado!", null));
  }
  
  return file;
 }
 
 public void excluirAnexo() {
  if(anexoHelp != null) {
   IArquivoAnexo arquivoAnexo = configuracaoFacade.recuperarAnexo(anexoHelp.getId());
   documento.excluirAnexo(arquivoAnexo);
   
   listaAnexo.remove(anexoHelp);
  }
  
  getListaAnexo();
 }
 
 private void preencherDatas() {
  if(documento.getDataDocumento() != null) {
   dataDocumento = DateUtils.getDate(documento.getDataDocumento());
  }  
 }
 
 public List<SelectItem> getOpcaoSelectItemList(IFiltro filtro) {
  Iterator<IOpcaoFiltro> iOpcaoFiltroList = filtro.getOpcaoFiltroList();
  List<SelectItem> selectItemOpcao = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
  
  selectItemOpcao.add(new SelectItem(null, "Selecione um Item"));
  while (iOpcaoFiltroList.hasNext()) {
   IOpcaoFiltro opcaoFiltro = iOpcaoFiltroList.next();
   selectItemOpcao.add(new SelectItem(opcaoFiltro, opcaoFiltro.getDescricao()));
  }
  
  return selectItemOpcao;
 }
 
 public List<IFiltro> getFiltroList() {
  return filtroList;
 }
 
 public boolean isRenderizaOpcoesFiltro() {
  return categoria.getFiltroList().hasNext();
 }

 public IDocumentoFacade getDocumentoFacade() {
  return documentoFacade;
 }

 public void setDocumentoFacade(IDocumentoFacade documentoFacade) {
  this.documentoFacade = documentoFacade;
 }

 public Long getCategoriaId() {
  return categoriaId;
 }

 public void setCategoriaId(Long categoriaId) {
  this.categoriaId = categoriaId;
 }

 public ICategoria getCategoria() {
  return categoria;
 }

 public void setCategoria(ICategoria categoria) {
  this.categoria = categoria;
 }

 public IDocumento getDocumento() {
  return documento;
 }

 public void setDocumento(IDocumento documento) {
  this.documento = documento;
 }

 public Date getDataDocumento() {
  return dataDocumento;
 }

 public void setDataDocumento(Date dataDocumento) {
  this.dataDocumento = dataDocumento;
 }

 public IConfiguracaoFacade getConfiguracaoFacade() {
  return configuracaoFacade;
 }

 public void setConfiguracaoFacade(IConfiguracaoFacade configuracaoFacade) {
  this.configuracaoFacade = configuracaoFacade;
 }

 public IArquivoAnexo getAnexo() {
  return anexo;
 }

 public void setAnexo(IArquivoAnexo anexo) {
  this.anexo = anexo;
 }

 public String getTamanhoArquivo() {
  return tamanhoArquivo;
 }

 public void setTamanhoArquivo(String tamanhoArquivo) {
  this.tamanhoArquivo = tamanhoArquivo;
 }
 
 public ArrayList<ArquivoAnexoHelp> getListaAnexo() {
  return listaAnexo;
 }
 
 public Long getDocumentoId() {
  return documentoId;
 }

 public void setDocumentoId(Long documentoId) {
  this.documentoId = documentoId;
 }

 public boolean isApresentaInformativo() {
  return apresentaInformativo;
 }

 public void setApresentaInformativo(boolean apresentaInformativo) {
  this.apresentaInformativo = apresentaInformativo;
 }

 public IOpcaoFiltro[] getOpcaoFiltroSelecionadaList() {
  return opcaoFiltroSelecionadaList;
 }

 public void setOpcaoFiltroSelecionadaList(IOpcaoFiltro[] opcaoFiltroSelecionadaList) {
  this.opcaoFiltroSelecionadaList = opcaoFiltroSelecionadaList;
 }
 
}
```

**Código web.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SysPortal</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
         /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml   
        </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>fileServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>br.com.sysmar.sysportal.security.FileServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>fileServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/usuario/file/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>fileServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/master/file/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>fileServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/gerenciador/file/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>fileServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/administrador/file/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>fileServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/public/file/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>fileServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/file/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>
   <filter>
     <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
     <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
 </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
     <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>encoding</param-name>
         <param-value>UTF8</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
     </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>commons</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Alguém sabe me dizer o que está havendo?
Obrigado desde já, pois realmente não consegui encontrar respostas em lugar algum.

Comment: Como  você só colocou um trecho do código html, verifique se a tag `form` possui o atributo `enctype` correto, por exemplo: `<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Resolvi o problema migrando do prime 5.1 para o 6.3